# Mocha tests do not start selenium browser

Tags: node.js, selenium, mocha.js

I would like to use Mocha+Selenium to test a webapp. I have installed WebDriverJS (via npm install webdriverjs), and Mocha (via npm install mocha).

When I run this code via node (node test.js), a new browser window is opened and it loads the page I want to test

```
var assert = require("assert");
var selenium_server="10.222.33.187",
    server_under_test="http://xxx.com/";
var webdriverjs = require('webdriverjs');

var client=webdriverjs.remote({
    host:selenium_server,
    port:4444,
});
client.init()
    .url(server_under_test);
```

If I run this code via Mocha (mocha test.js), it doesn't start a new browser. the test just passes, without starting the browser

```
var assert = require("assert");
var selenium_server="10.222.33.187",
    server_under_test="http://trapspotter.com/alpha/";
var webdriverjs = require('webdriverjs');

before(function() {
    var client=webdriverjs.remote({
        host:selenium_server,
        port:4444,
    });
    client.init()
        .url(server_under_test);
});

describe("test", function() {
    it("should pass", function() {
        assert(true);
    });
});
```

Any insights into why the Mocha test doesn't start the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by passing done to url()

```
describe("test", function() {
    before(function(done) {
        client.init()
            .url(server_under_test, done);
    });
    it("should pass", function() {
        assert(true);
    });
});
```